# / and /blog are not not showing any of the content from Posts. I believe the issue has something to do with get_absolute_url() and reverse

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

While /blog doesn't show any of the posts, / is showing empty bootstrap modules for every post - so it knows how many posts there are and therefore something is coming through.

I believe the issue started when I attempted to add another module to base.html

The directory structure is as follows:

```
 - src [Folder] 
   - content [Folder]
     - migrations [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - admin.py
     - apps.py
     - models.py
     - tests.py
     - views.py
  - main [Folder]
     - settings [Folder]
         - __init__.py
         - base.py
     - migrations [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - db.sqlite3
     - models.py
     - urls.py
     - views.py
     - wsgi.py
  - posts [Folder]
     - migrations [Folder]
     - templatetags [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - admin.py
     - apps.py
     - forms.py
     - models.py
     - tests.py
     - urls.py
     - utils.py
     - views.py
    - templates
     - base.html
     - blogbase.htm
```

models.py - posts is as follows:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.text import slugify


from markdown_deux import markdown
from comments.models import Comment

from .utils import get_read_time
# Create your models here.
# MVC MODEL VIEW CONTROLLER


#Post.objects.all()
#Post.objects.create(user=user, title="Some time")

class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Post.objects.all() = super(PostManager, self).all()
        return super(PostManager, self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    #filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    #return "%s/%s.%s" %(instance.id, instance.id, extension)
    PostModel = instance.__class__
    new_id = PostModel.objects.order_by("id").last().id + 1
    """
    instance.__class__ gets the model Post. We must use this method because the model is defined below.
    Then create a queryset ordered by the "id"s of each object, 
    Then we get the last object in the queryset with `.last()`
    Which will give us the most recently created Model instance
    We add 1 to it, so we get what should be the same id as the the post we are creating.
    """
    return "%s/%s" %(new_id, filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
            null=True, 
            blank=True, 
            width_field="width_field", 
            height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    read_time =  models.IntegerField(default=0) # models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True) #assume minutes
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]

    def get_markdown(self):
        content = self.content
        markdown_text = markdown(content)
        return mark_safe(markdown_text)

    @property
    def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type


def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

    if instance.content:
        html_string = instance.get_markdown()
        read_time_var = get_read_time(html_string)
        instance.read_time = read_time_var


pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

my urls.py - posts is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import (
    home,
    post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^blog$', post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^blog/create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),
    #url(r'^posts/$', "<appname>.views.<function_name>"),
]
```

my urls.py - main is as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.views.generic import ListView

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)
# from main.views import MyView
from views import MyView

from posts.views import (
    home,
    post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
    )

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^comments/', include("comments.urls", namespace='comments')),

    url(r'^register/', register_view, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(template_name=('base.html')), name='name'),
    url(r'^', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
    #url(r'^posts/$', "<appname>.views.<function_name>"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The view for posts/ is as follows:

```
try:
    from urllib import quote_plus #python 2
except:
    pass

try:
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus #python 3
except: 
    pass

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone

from comments.forms import CommentForm
from comments.models import Comment
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post



def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)

def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)

    initial_data = {
            "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
            "object_id": instance.id
    }
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        parent_obj = None
        try:
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get("parent_id"))
        except:
            parent_id = None

        if parent_id:
            parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
            if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
                parent_obj = parent_qs.first()


        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            user = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            content = content_data,
                            parent = parent_obj,
                        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.content_object.get_absolute_url())


    comments = instance.comments
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
        "comments": comments,
        "comment_form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Post.objects.active() #.order_by("-timestamp")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(content__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)


def post_update(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "<a href='#'>Item</a> Saved", extra_tags='html_safe')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)



def post_delete(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
    return redirect("posts:list")

def home(request, slug=None):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Post.objects.active()[:1] #.order_by("-timestamp")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()[:1]

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(content__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "base.html", context)
```

the view for / is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin


from posts.models import Post
from content.models import Content

class DashboardTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"
    context_object_name = 'name'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardTemplateView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["title"] = "This is about us"
        return context

class MyView(ContextMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # mission_statement = Content.objects.filter(Content.objects.title == 'test')
        # context = {'mission_statement' : mission_statement,
        #           'content_list' : Content.objects.all(),
        #           'post_list' : Post.objects.all()}
        context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'post_list':Post.objects.all()}
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

template for / is as follows

```
{% for post in post_list %}
<div class="section" id="blog">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <a href="/blog"><h1>Blog</h1></a>
                <br>
                <p>Come Check out our Blog for the most up to date information on how you can best help your child!</p>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h2><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.title }}</a> <small>{{ obj.publish }}</small></h2>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    {% if obj.image %}
                     <img src='{{ obj.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                  <div class="caption post-detail-item">
                    {% if obj.draft %}<h3>Staff only: Draft</h3>{% endif %} {% if obj.publish > today %}<h3>Staff Only: Future Post</h3>{% endif %}
                    {% if obj.user.get_full_name %}<p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}</p>{% endif %}
                    {{ obj.get_markdown|truncatechars_html:120 }}
                    <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary outline" role="button">Continue Reading</a></p>
                  </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

template for /blogbase.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block head_title %}Swanson Speech Therapy Blog{% endblock head_title %}</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' >

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href='{% static "img/blue-talk.ico" %}' type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href='{% static "img/blue-talk.ico" %}' type="image/x-icon">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/blogbase.css" %}'/>
<style>
{% block style %}{% endblock style %}
</style>

{% block head_extra %} {% endblock head_extra %}
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div id="fb-root"></div> -->
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="header">
    <div class="logos container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><p></p></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><<p></p></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><p></p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



{% include "messages_display.html" %}
<div class='container'>
    <ol class='breadcrumb'>
        <li><a href='{% url "posts:list" %}'>Home</a></li>
        {% block post_detail_link %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class='pull-right'><a href='{% url "register" %}'>Register</a></li>
        <li class='pull-right'><a href='{% url "login" %}'>Login</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class='pull-right'><a href='{% url "logout" %}'>Logout</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ol>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>





<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content-markdown").each(function(){
            var content = $(this).text()
            var markedContent = marked(content)
            $(this).html(markedContent)
    })
    $(".post-detail-item img").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("img-responsive");
    })



    var contentInput = $("#id_content");

    function setContent(value){
        var markedContent = marked(value)
        $("#preview-content").html(markedContent)
        $("#preview-content img").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("img-responsive")
        })
    }
    setContent(contentInput.val())

    contentInput.keyup(function(){
        var newContent = $(this).val()
        setContent(newContent)
    })

    var titleInput = $("#id_title");



    function setTitle(value) {
        $("#preview-title").text(value)
    }
    setTitle(titleInput.val())

    titleInput.keyup(function(){
        var newContent = $(this).val()
        setTitle(newContent)
    })

    $(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
    })


    // preview-title
    // preview-content

})

</script>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 about-footer">
            <p><strong>Swanson Speech Therapy provides quality speech and language therapy in Ballard, Seattle, WA. My goal is to enrich communication for each child and family that I work with. I specialize in early language development, receptive and expressive language delays and disorders, articulation delays, childhood apraxia of speech, and children with social communication difficulties and/or a diagnosis of Autism Spectrum Disorder.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row menu-social-row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 footer-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#blog"><strong>Blog</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials"><strong>Testimonials</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#rates"><strong>Rates</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#faq"><strong>FAQ</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/swansonspeechtherapy/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/natalie-swanson-929a5128/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <!-- <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> -->
                <!-- <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> -->
                <li><a href="https://www.yelp.com/biz/swanson-speech-therapy-seattle"><i class="fa fa-yelp fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/109457962152224647107"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="no-bottom-margin">
    <div class="row footer-footer">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't shown the view or template for either `/` or `/blog`.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for helping/looking

Comment: You haven't shown the template for either `/` or `/blog`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Edited again.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables do not match in your template. You look though

```
{% for post in post_list %}
```

But inside the loop you use `obj` instead of `post`, e.g.

```
{{ obj.image.url }}
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you for this. This fixed the problem in '/'

It didn't fix the problem in '/blog' , which seems to have the correct variables

Comment: It's not clear what your template for the `/blog` url is -- however, I don't see anything that loops through `object_list` from your template context.